# WPF TextBox disable break on special characters

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a `TextBox` defined like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding License.LicenseKey}"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
         TextAlignment="Justify"
         Width="350"
         Height="100"
         Margin="10,0,0,0"
         TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Currently a long string will break on special characters:

[image]

I would prefer it to simply break on any character once it reaches the end of the `TextBox` like this:

[image]

Is there a way to disable the stock breaking that a `TextBox` uses?  I have tried various options for `TextAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` to no avail.

Comment: You could add a zero-width space (U+200B) after each character which would allow a break at any position. So would need do define a property in your view model, you would to and whose getter would do this transformation, e.g. string SomeProperty { get { return String.Join(string.Empty, License.LicenseKey.Zip(new string('\u200B', License.LicenseKey.Length), (x, y) => x.ToString() + y)); } set { Model.LicenseKey = value; } }, so that it is displayed with line breaks. However I don't know what would happen to the cursor position.

Comment: Also the binding would probably need UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, so that it updates immediately.

Comment: This does indeed work. Any sideeffect when copy/pasting the text with all the zero-width spaces?

Comment: Yes, one would have a problem if one copies the text and pastes it back to the textbox. However you could change the setter to Model.LicenseKey = value?.Replace("\u200B", string.Empty) to avoid these characters being written to Model.LicenseKey.

Comment: On an afterthought, I think it is absolutely required to change the setter to what I have written last, as otherwise everytime you add an character to the checkbox WPF would use the modified string and again add the zero-width joiners which would explosively expanding the string.

Comment: @ckuri Your solution worked for me.  If you would like to make this an answer I will mark it as excepted.

Comment: @BrianKE Glad, I could help you. As you suggested I have converted my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a zero-width space (U+200B) after each character which would allow a break at any position. You would need to define a property in your view model and bind to it, and have the getter do this transformation so that it is displayed with line breaks, e.g.:

```
string SomeProperty
{
  get { return String.Join(string.Empty, License.LicenseKey.Zip(new string('\u200B', License.LicenseKey.Length), (x, y) => x.ToString() + y)); }
  set { Model.LicenseKey = value?.Replace("\u200B", string.Empty); }
}
```

However I don't know what would happen to the cursor position.

Comment: The only problem is that the zero-width spaces are included when copying to the clipboard. You have to override the copy command for the TextBox so it removes these spaces before saving to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is exceptionally messy due to limited options on the TextBox's TextWrapping property.

See this [forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3cb5b7a8-5628-4dc3-bd43-be67d1a449b1/how-to-customizing-textblock-line-breaking-algorithm-in-textwrapping?forum=wpf) to explain the U+200B comment below your question. However, that doesn't work for you because you DON'T want it to break. And if there's a library of standard non-breaking versions of characters, I've been unable to dig it up.

The only way I see this working is to use a fixed-width font, keeping track of how many characters are entered alongside the capacity of the box, and adding your own newline when that capacity is reached.